# How to turn off browser auto-fill Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.2

I'm looking to turn off browser autofill feature on checkout, the [solution](http://help.onestepcheckout.com/knowledge_base/topics/browser-autofill) is added `autocomplete="false"` in the form tag.

> e.g) `<form autocomplete="false">`

In Magento 2 using UI components, I don't see any form tag on view page source.

any idea how to turn off browser autofill?